# Is there any better way to ignore \n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

My test started failing because I added a `debugger` after an XML expected block. Now it produces a single `\n` at the end of the statement that fails my test. And I can't seem to get rid of it anyway I delete or move around my text.

Then I wrote this to make it pass :

```
      expected = <<-XML
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <?qbxml version="5.0" ?>
    <QBXML>
      <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
      </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>
    XML
  assert_equal expected.gsub(/\n/,'').gsub(' ',''), result.gsub(/\n/,'').gsub(' ','')
  #assert_equal expected.strip, result
```

Otherwise the commented out one used to work. Is there some dumb obvious sense I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not compare strings, it just sucks.

Instead I would compare the object representations.

Try to use: Hash#from_xml and compare the hashes.

Comment: I'd say: [me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987024/difference-between-two-xml-documents-ruby-on-rails), and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072005/how-do-i-compare-xml-output-in-a-cucumber-step-using-a-multiline-string-example)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\s` in the regular expression to replace both the new line and space characters, it's a bit more readable:

```
assert_equal expected.gsub(/\s/,''), result.gsub(/\s/,'')
```